# How can I parse a string as html or maybe how can I dynamic add a complex html by clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, string, dynamic, createelement

I need to insert this html tree when I click a button

```
<div class='img-wrapper'> <img id='immagine_preview' width='200px' height='200px' data-id_immagine='1'><button type='button' class='rimuoviImg' ><span class='fa fa-times'></span></button></div>
```

I tried this code, but it returns me a body tag with my html inside it.

```
     var stringToHTML = function (str) {
             
             var parser = new DOMParser();
             var doc = parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
             return doc.body;
             };
```

I need to dynamically add the previous html elements before an upload button (I use a before() method with the stringToHTML function inside and it works). There is a simpler way to do this?. Because I learnt that the documen.createElement doesn't work with a complex argument.

Thank to all community to the help they gave me even with my previous questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a html variable with template literal and inside that you can write your html semantic then you can use insertAdjacentHTML()

Comment: You're welcome. I'll be appreciated if you choose my answer as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could just append the HTML to the element's innerHTML:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.body.innerHTML += `<div class='img-wrapper'> <img id='immagine_preview' width='200px' height='200px' data-id_immagine='1'><button type='button' class='rimuoviImg' ><span class='fa fa-times'></span></button></div>`;
})
```

```html
<button>Insert HTML</button>
```

Comment: Ok, thank you, it works well. But how could I let this code appear where I want?

Comment: @Tonio What do you mean by 'where I want'?

Comment: with your code the html would be appended to the end of the body

Comment: Replace `document.body` with the element you wish to append the HTML to.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to contain the HTML, and when you click the button use [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to add it to an existing element.

```js
const str = `
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img id="immagine_preview" width="200px" height="200px" data-id_immagine="1">
    <button type="button" class="rimuoviImg">
      <span class="fa fa-times"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
`
// Cache the element you want to markup to appear,
// and the button
const div = document.querySelector('div');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

// Add a click listener to the button, and insert
// the markup to the chosen element.
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);
});
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
<div />
```